# Using VSPerfCmd 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling, profiler

I'm trying to profile a C++ program with Visual Studio 2019, community edition. The available documentation, which dates from a few years ago, says VSPerfCmd is the relevant tool, but also prescribes using the `/launch` switch to run the program, and VSPerfCmd now says that switch is no longer valid, but its help documentation gives no hint what to use instead.

What is the current command line syntax for VSPerfCmd?

(I'm aware it no longer offers sample mode. It claims to still offer something called trace mode; I'm hoping to get it running so I can see whether that's useful.)

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2019 many of the previous profiler features were deprecated. One of the modifications to the legacy profiling features has to do with the sampling methodology for performnce profiling. All sampling operations are now provided by a different set of tools. As a result, VSPerfCmd options related to sampling have been removed.

In order to get sampling behavior with Visual Studio 2019 one must use the newer tools. In the IDE this is available for the `ALT-F2 Performance Profiler` (aka the Diagnostics Hub). The command line options for sampling are available via `VSDiagnostics.exe`. You could refer to Microsoft Docs about [VSDiagnostics.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profile-apps-from-command-line?view=vs-2019).